# Redundant/Failover Ethernet Link from Windows Server to Switch

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm trying to set up a redundant link from my Windows server (Dell R710 with 4 GigE ports) to my Cisco switch. I'd like to "failover" in case the first Ethernet link fails (e.g. NIC issue, cable issue). How would I go about doing this? Didn't find much on Google. I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

If your switch supports it I'd recommending bonding the ports together. When you've got all 4 ports bonded you should be able to have any one of them go down, unless theres an issue with the nic, and the rest continue transmitting.

Here's a [LINK](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2010/09/03/using-the-multiple-nics-of-your-file-server-running-windows-server-2008-and-2008-r2.aspx) to a pretty decent article on bonding your NICs.
Here's a [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation) to a wiki article on LACP, which is what your switch needs.

Comment: Can you please give me some info on how to set this up on the windows side? The NIC is a Broadcom 5709c.

Comment: Added a link in the answer, one thing to keep in mind you should make sure your switch is going to support it. If its a low end Cisco product theres a chance it wont.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Looking at it now. For the switch side, it's a Cisco SG300-28. On the cisco site (http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps10898/data_sheet_c78-610061.html) it says under "Port Grouping" that it has "Support for IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregation Control Protocol (LACP)" - is that what I need?

Comment: Yup, LACP is what you want. Heres a wiki article on it.

Answer (score 0):

Bonding is one way to go, perhaps the right way to go.

The quick and dirty way, 2 separate NIC, 2 separate IPs, 2 separate switch ports, 1 DNS entry using round robin.